# Creating a python loop/ list comprehension that contains all the multiples of 1 to 100 that are under 100

Tags: python, list

I want to create a python list comprehension statement that contains all the multiples of 2 to 100 that are under 100 and puts them inside a list. I understand this statement is probably very confusing so here how it would work in my mind:

1. Start from 2, add all the multiples of 2 to a list. IE. 2, 4, 6, 8... 100..
2. Move onto the next number, 3, add all the multiple of 3 to the same list(keeping it under 100) IE. 3, 6, 9, …99
3. Repeat this for all number from 2 to 99, placing all the values inside one singular list
4. In the end, my list should  pretty much contain every number from 1 to 100 that is not prime.

I want to achieve this using **list comprehension** if possible. I've attached my work in the bottom which is not working. Right now, my loop just prints the multiple of 2 100 times and I am having trouble figuring out how to change the number being multiplied and storing it in one entire list.

Note: The point of my list is to filter out the prime numbers later, in the fashion of the Sieve of Eratosthenes but I don't need help with that part. See my code below:

```
print([i for i  in range(100) if [x+x for x in range(100) if i + i <= 100]])
```

Comment: In my early days with Python I often found it helpful to write the operation as a regular loop first, and then converting it to a list comprehension

Comment: @PranavHosangadi a great benefit of that method is that you can step through it in a debugger more easily.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my early days with Python I often found it helpful to write the operation as a regular loop first, and then converting it to a list comprehension

I'm going to use a *set* comprehension in my answer because sets get rid of the duplicates, so you don't have to worry about checking if a number is already in the list.

For example:

```
multiples = set()

for i in range(2, 101): # Loop over numbers
    for j in range(2, 100//i + 1): # Loop over multiplications
        multiples.add(i * j)
```

The inner loop goes from `2` (because you don't want to add every number to the set) to `100//ii + 1` (because `100//i` is the highest multiple of `i` that is `<= 100`, and `+ 1` because `range()` excludes the end).

Writing this as a <strike>list</strike>set comprehension now is easy:

```
multiples = {i * j for i in range(2, 101) for j in range(2, 100//i + 1)}
```

To quickly pick out the numbers that *aren't* in this set, you can create a set containing all numbers from `2` (because `1` isn't prime) to `100` and get the set difference.

```
primes = set(range(2, 101)) - multiples
```

which gives:

```
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and logic explanation! I understand it! Would it be possible to achieve this without a set and set() function and instead do it with a traditional list [ ]? If so, what would be different between the two, and is it possible?

Comment: @saul212 Sure. I mentioned in my answer why I used a set. It should work fine with lists. You just need to check if the number already exists in the list before appending it to the list in the loop. Unfortunately you can't do this in a list comprehension, so you'll have to create the full list with all duplicates, and _then_ ignore or get rid of the duplicates. Also remember that finding a number in the list will be more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just an observation about how list comprehension could be slower than a multiline program.

This program is an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  One line added to @Pranav's solution could eliminate running through the table with unnecessary divisors.  e.g.

```
multiples = set()

for i in range(2, 101): # Loop over numbers
    if not i in multiples:
       for j in range(2, 100//i + 1): # Loop over multiplications
           multiples.add(i * j)
```

I don't believe that could be done with any kind of list comprehension.